# How to Remove meta title tag in magento 2

Tags: magento2, meta-title

I have issue any time in meta="title" and  both are display all Pages So i have Remove Meta="Title" Using File Override In Magento Core Module

Answer (score 4):

Finally I got solution. Please check below code

> Create di.xml File in your Custom module

```
<preference for="Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer" type="Module\Demo\View\Page\Config\Rendererfile" />
```

**Rendererfile.php**

```
<?php

    namespace Module\Demo\View\Page\Config;

    use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
    use Magento\Framework\View\Asset\GroupedCollection;
    use Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config;

    class Rendererfile extends \Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer
    {

        protected function getMetadataTemplate($name)
        {
            if (strpos($name, 'og:') === 0) {
                return '<meta property="' . $name . '" content="%content"/>' . "\n";
            }

            switch ($name) {
                case Config::META_CHARSET:
                    $metadataTemplate = '<meta charset="%content"/>' . "\n";
                    break;

                case Config::META_CONTENT_TYPE:
                    $metadataTemplate = '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="%content"/>' . "\n";
                    break;

                case Config::META_X_UI_COMPATIBLE:
                    $metadataTemplate = '<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="%content"/>' . "\n";
                    break;

                case Config::META_MEDIA_TYPE:
                    $metadataTemplate = false;
                    break;

                default:
                if ($name === 'title') {
                     $metadataTemplate = '';
                }
                else
                {

                    $metadataTemplate = '<meta name="%name" content="%content"/>' . "\n";
                }
                    break;
            }
            return $metadataTemplate;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Create your plugin extension and add below code on di.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config">
        <plugin name="unsetMetaTitle" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\PageConfig\unsetMetaTitle" sortOrder="9999"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Create unsetMetaTitle.php file into Plugin\PageConfig folder

```
declare(strict_types = 1);
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\PageConfig;

class unsetMetaTitle
{
    public function afterGetMetaTitle($subject, string $return)
    {
        return '';
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not working in magento2.3.1 so please refer my above answer